# Use a service in twig without create a twig extension

Tags: twig, symfony, twig-filter

I have a service class :

```
namespace App\DesktopBundle\Lib;

class MediaManager
{
    // media image path
    protected $media_url;

    /**
     * Constructor of class
     * @param $media_url
     */
    public function __construct($media_url) 
    {
        $this->image_url = $media_url;
    }

    public function getImage($media_type, $url){
        return sprintf("%s/%s/%s", $this->image_url, $media_type, $url);
    }
}
```

In `/src/App/DesktopBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` I have :

```
services:
    media_manager:
        class: App\DesktopBundle\Lib\MediaManager
        arguments: [%media_url%, "media_type","url"]
```

In `/app/config/config.yml` I have :

```
twig:
    globals:
        mediaService: "@media_manager"
```

In template I try :

```
<img src="{{ asset(mediaService.getImage('gifts','150x150')) }}" alt="team member img">
```

But I have the error : `Variable "mediaService" does not exist in`. Can you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are loaded your `services.yml` into `DesktopExtension.php` ?

Comment: your code works fine, check the tips of @Yonel

Comment: @Yonel how to do that ?